# Python client.Dispatch("outlook.application") fails in specific case (@company emails)

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

#### Hi there,

Everything is working fine, except one thing I can't send email to clients that have non-standard email (if their email are @gmail, @outlook, etc, it sends the email normally)

I have a client with the following email client@company.com (not the real email obviously), I can't send that email to him. There goes my method. I'd love some help.

mail.Send()

> File "", line 2, in Send pywintypes.com_error:
> (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)

```
def main_send_email(self, to, header, attached_msg, pdf_files=None):
    import pythoncom
    # return super().main_send_email(to, header, attached_msg, pdf_files)
    self.outlook_app = client.Dispatch(
        'outlook.application', pythoncom.CoInitialize())
    s = client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
    mail = self.outlook_app.CreateItem(0)

    # set the account
    account = None
    for acc in mail.Session.Accounts:
        if "39" in acc.DisplayName:
            account = acc
    mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, account))
    # mail.SendUsingAccount = self.outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
    # set email sender
    # mail.To = 'silsilinhas@gmail.com'
    mail.To = to
    mail.Subject = header
    mail.HTMLBody = attached_msg
    if pdf_files is not None:
        for pdf in pdf_files:
            mail.Attachments.Add(pdf)
    mail.Send()
```

Comment: What is the value assigned to the `to` variable?. It sure sounds like the recipient cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In a program i wrote I have found the error "(-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)" whenever I try using mail.Send() before calling mail.Display().

Seems fairly consistent but can't explain why!
Hope this helps (sorry if it doesn't!)

```
...
if pdf_files is not None:
       for pdf in pdf_files:
          mail.Attachments.Add(pdf)
mail.Display()  ##this line here  
mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've noticed the following line of code which is useless and never used:

```
s = client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
```

It seems there is no need to create a new MAPI session in the code if you automate Outlook.

Second, the `Send` method may trigger a security issue when automating Outlook from external applications. It can be a security prompt or just an exception thrown at runtime. There are several ways for suppressing such prompts/issues:

- Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
- Use a low-level API which doesn't trigger such issues/prompts instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, Redemption.
- Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted `Application` object. And then communicate from a standalone application with an add-in using standard .Net tools (Remoting).
- Use group policy objects for setting up machines to not throw such issues.
- Install the latest AV software.

Third, you may try to set recipients for the mail item using the `Recipients` collection which provides the [Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book. Read more about that in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.